# Why access qualifier is not considered when virtual function is overridden?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding

Following code prints "I'm B!". It's a bit strange because `B::foo()` is private. About `A* ptr` we can say that its static type is `A` (`foo` is public) and its dynamic type is `B` (`foo` is private). So I can invoke `foo` via pointer to `A`. But this way I have access to private function in `B`. Can it be considered as encapsulation violation?

Since access qualifier is not part of class method signature it can lead to such strange cases. Why does in C++ access qualifier is not considered when virtual function is overridden? Can I prohibit such cases? What design principle is behind this decision?

[Live example](http://rextester.com/live/GWIX76571).

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm A!\n";
    };
};

class B: public A
{
private:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm B!\n";
    };
};

int main()
{
    A* ptr;
    B b;

    ptr = &b;

    ptr->foo();
}
```

Comment: You are calling `A::foo()` and that is public. You are not allowed to call `b.foo()`directly. The big question is why is `B::foo` private?

Comment: @Bo Persson Sure. But `B::foo` is called.

Comment: @Bo Persson Yes it is a question. I think compiler can generate warning about this.

Comment: Assume you have a function `void f(A* a) { a->foo(); }` is a separately compiled file. How is the compiler to know if you later pass a `B`, or a `C`, or an `A`?. The interface says that the function is public, so it is.

Comment: You are calling public `A::foo` method. And it is not an encapsulation violation for the same reason as there is no encapsulation violation occurring just because `A::foo` (not virtual) called some private method or modified some private field. Encapsulation violation could emerge if this method was left public, but was performing something that outside code shouldn't be allowed to do.

Comment: @Bo Persson I mean warning pointing to private  overridden function when is public in base class. It is not too complex I my opinion.

Comment: @Viktor Why do you want a warning? The case is perfectly fine and I don't see any problems with that. If you have a problem there, then that's probably a flaw in your design.

Comment: @user0042 I agree it is design error that public function in base class became private. My point is that compiler can catch this error.

Comment: There is no _error to catch_. I've been using such stuff intentionally before the `class final` feature was available.

Comment: @user0042 could you give an example how does this approach interleave with `final`?

Comment: @Viktor It doesn't really, but prevents from further overriding in derived classes (makes further deriving classes useless).

Comment: @Viktor [Here](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/blob/master/sttcl/include/State.h)'s an example of intentional use in the `StateBase` class. Inheriting classes should be forced to stick to the static polymorphic interface.

Comment: @user0042 thanks for example!

Comment: Access control applies to declaration. The named declaration is in the base class. Access control doesn't apply to objects (hopefully).

Comment: Access control applies to names in scopes. The name `B::foo` is private but that doesn't mean "the function is private". Similarly you can return pointers to private variables in a public function, etc.

Comment: There's a style of C++ coding where all virtual functions are private, and are exposed to users through non-virtual wrappers. It's perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple questions, so I'll try to answer them one-by-one.

### Why is in C++ access qualifier not considered when virtual function is overridden?

Because access qualifiers are taken into account by the compiler after all overload resolutions. 
Such behavior is prescribed by the Standard.

For example, see [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> Member access does not affect visibility: names of private and privately-inherited members are visible and considered by overload resolution, implicit conversions to inaccessible base classes are still considered, etc. **Member access check is the last step after any given language construct is interpreted**. The intent of this rule is that replacing any private with public never alters the behavior of the program.

The next paragraph described the behavior demonstrated by your example:

> Access rules for the names of virtual functions are checked at the call point **using the type of the expression used to denote the object for which the member function is called. The access of the final overrider is ignored.**

Also see the sequence of actions listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863625).

### Can I prohibit such cases?

No.

And I don't think you will ever be able to do so, because there's nothing illegal in this behavior.

### What design principle is behind this decision?

Just to clarify: by "decision" here I imply the prescription for the compiler to check the access qualifiers after overload resolution.
The short answer: to prevent surprises when you're changing your code.

For more details let's assume you're developing some `CoolClass` which looks like this

```
class CoolClass {
public:
  void doCoolStuff(int coolId); // your class interface
private:
  void doCoolStuff(double coolValue); // auxiliary method used by the public one
};
```

Assume that compiler can do overload resolution based on public/private specifiers. Then the following code would successfully compile:

```
CoolClass cc;
cc.doCoolStuff(3.14); // invokes CoolClass::doCoolStuff(int)
  // yes, this would raise the warning, but it can be ignored or suppressed
```

Then at some point you discover that your private member function is actually useful for the class client and move it to "public" area. This automatically *changes the behavior of the preexisting client code*, since now it invokes `CoolClass::doCoolStuff(double)`.

So the rules of applying access qualifiers are written in a manner that does **not** allow such cases, so instead you will get the "ambiguous call" compiler error in the very beginning. And virtual functions are no special case for the same reason (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786209)).

### Can it be considered as encapsulation violation?

Not really.
By converting pointer to your class into a pointer to its base class you're actually saying: "Herewith I would like to use this object B as if it's an object A" - which is perfectly legal, because the inheritance implies "as-is" relation.

So the question is rather, can your example be considered as violating contract prescribed by the base class? It seems that yes, it can.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484592/overriding-public-virtual-functions-with-private-functions-in-c) for alternative explanation.

### P.S.

Don't get me wrong, all this doesn't mean at all that you shouldn't use private virtual functions. On the contrary, *it's often considered as a good practice*, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170688/private-virtual-method-in-c). But they should be private from the very base class. So again, the bottom line is, you should not use private virtual functions to break public contracts.

P.P.S. ...unless you deliberately want to force client to use your class via the pointer to interface / base class. But there are better ways for that, and I believe the discussion of those lies beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Access qualifiers like `public`, `private`, etc. are a compile time feature, while dynamic polymorphism is a runtime feature.

What do you think should happen at runtime when a `private` override of a `virtual` function is called? An exception?

> Can it be considered as encapsulation violation?

No, since the interface is already published through the inheritance, it isn't.

It's perfectly fine (and might be intended), to override a `public virtual` function from the base class with a `private` function in the derived class.

Comment: I don't know how other languages deal with it.

Comment: May be warning  during compilation is good enough is this case.

Comment: @Viktor Why a warning or such? It's perfectly fine.

Comment: in C# it leads to error http://rextester.com/live/HWZAC43306. What logic is behind not to implement so in C++ ?

Comment: @Viktor Shrug, different languages?

Comment: In C++ it is not intuitively clear. May be some principal restrictions in compilation process can explain the reason?

Comment: @Viktor As mentioned, it's not an error. No further reasoning (think about it as a feature).